# VBA worksheet change with multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a named range that I'm monitoring in a `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`.  I noticed that if the user selects multiple cells in that range and does a right-click-->Clear, the program crashes.

I have code that looks like :

```
If Target <> "" And (.Cells(Target.Row, [GLB_Location_Col].Column) = "" _
    Or .Cells(Target.Row, [GLB_LineType_Col].Column) = "") Then                   
    .Cells(Target.Row, [GLB_Location_Col].Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 40  'peach
    .Cells(Target.Row, [GLB_LineType_Col].Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 40  'peach
```

My code is assuming 1 cell is being changed at a time, so I guess when a range gets passed to one of my `.Cell` functions, it doesn't know how to handle it and throws a mismatch error.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First ensure that the code runs if only 1 cell is selected.

```
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    '~~> rest of code here
End If
```

**Note:** For newer versions of Excel (e.g. XL2007 and up) you'll need to use `CountLarge` property to avoid overflow error.

Now, to test for specific ranges only, then integrate [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) function in your `If` statement. Something like:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, .Cells(1, [GLB_Location_Col].Column).EntireColumn) Is Nothing _
And .Cells(Target.Row, [GLB_Location_Col].Column) <> "" Then
```

So it checks first if `Target` range is within the entire `GLB_Location_Col` (which I assumed a named Range) and also if the range is not empty. HTH.